# Why can't I access managed bean methods from a JSF2 page?

Tags: file-upload, jsf-2, richfaces, listener

In a `<rich:popupPanel />` I have a `<rich:fileUpload />` which has a `fileUploadListener` defined as #{assemblyMB.listener}. This listener method is defined on the managed bean as:

```
public void listener(FileUploadEvent event) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("listener");
}
```

on the JSF page I have:

```
<rich:fileUpload id="popupFileUpload"
    fileUploadListener="#{assemblyMB.listener}"
    onuploadcomplete="#{rich:component('popup')}.hide(); return false;"
</rich:fileUpload>
```

On the managed bean, I have declared the annotation @ManagedBean(name = "assemblyMB").

I intend to access the method on the managed bean when the file is uploaded, but I'm failing to do so. I don't understand why is that happening.

Can anybody throw me a light here? Thanks in advance,

gtludwig

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming RichFaces 4.0, all you need to ensure is that the parent `<h:form>` is set to encode the request body as `multipart/form-data`.

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

This way the file should be uploaded properly and the listener method should be invoked when the upload has been arrived in the server side.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time! Yes, Richfaces 4.0. But still have nothing displayed on console. The <h:form> tag is set on the template file, could this be the reason? I think the file is being uploaded, for when I access the <rich:fileUpload> component on the page after the file being uploaded, it pops up <rich:popupPanel> (intended action) and the file is listed there.